# Laravel 5.1 - Variable in main blade layout

Tags: variables, laravel, global-variables, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1. And I have a problem about variable in my Layout View.

In my Layout view, I use a variable to show an active login user like this one on my `DashboardController`:

```
...
class DashboardController extends Controller {

        public function index(Request $request) {
            //
            $title = "Dashboard";
            $userActive = $request->user();
            return view('dashboard.index', compact('title', 'userActive'));
        }
...
```

The `$userActive` is to show who is login. My problem is i need to write this (the `$userActive`) code like above if I use another function, or another Contoller.

How to make it simple by write it only once?

Comment: The request has to be send to one url, it can't be send to everyone because then every get Route has also to be a post route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you access the Auth class inside your blade. Try it:

`{{ Auth::user()->name }}`

If you use Sentry:

`{{ Sentry::getUser()->name }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the *Auth* class inside your blade template to access the currently logged in user:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Alternatively you could try using a view composer: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to use the share() method. For example, you can add the following code in your AppServiceProvider :

```
view()->share('currentUser', Auth::user());
```

This way in any view you can access the logged in user via the $currentUser variable.
Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 0):

My approach in this case:

create a views/includes/menu.blade.php file and include it in app.blade.php file:

```
@include('includes.menu')
```

instead calling the `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` always you need to use the menu, on menu.blade.php put as suggested the following `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` on the menu file.